# How to resolve this error in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-connect

How to resolve this error in lightning. I dint know why this is come in lightning experince winter 16. I have follow this link and create a lightning application.
[enter link description here](http://ccoenraets.github.io/getting-started-lightning-components/index.html)

But it is working fine on 12 june. But after new release of winter 16.it is not working my google map is not showing. please help why this is happens?I have add its image.and error is this:

**This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: 0555182e-441d-43fc-af32-f1369dac32e1)** [image]

Answer (score 2):

The underlying error is:

> Uncaught Action failed: c$AccountMap$controller$accountsLoaded
>   [TypeError: L.marker is not a function]

this looks like an issue with LockerService although we have working examples using Leaflet.js - under Setup | Critical Updates you should be able to deactivate Locker Service for now until figure out what the issue is.